# Windows Server Versions Differences

Tags: windows

What is the big differences between windows server 2012, windows home server, windows small business server?

Are there any real differences or what are they designed for.

Answer (score 1):

Different limitations that I think are hard-coded by Microsoft (as oppose to limitations by some technicalities).

In [this comparison guide for server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38809), for example, you can see that the server 2012 essentials supports only 64GB while the standard supports 4TB.

There might be some other docs like this one with even more details.